# Desired probability distribution

Tags: python, statistics, cdf, probability-density

I have a data **"zcosmo"** that follows a certain distribution. It has many fluctuations **(i.e it increases slightly at some point and then flattens etc, but overall it increases from 0 to 0.5)**. So I fit the data using a function that follows the distribution of the data.

`This function is the probability distribution lets say of the data`. **Here in this image, the fit gives me the blue line, which I want to use as the probabilty distribution function.**

[image]

```
def fit(x,p1,p2):
    return (p1*x)+(p2*(x**2))
```

**Now I theoretically know how to create data that follows this function!**

- 1) compute the selection function in redshift from the distribution
  of cluster redshifts (the fitted function) and normalize it to unity
  **to have a probability distribution, say p(y)**
- 2) compute the    indefinite integral of the probability distribution
  F(y)= sum (from 0    to y) p(y)dy
- 3) throw a random number uniform    deviate x between 0 and    1
- 4) compute y = F-1(x)

**"y"** will then have the desired probability distribution p(y)

**`I am struggling to find a way to do it in Python. Is there a package that does the above??`**

Comment: What part can't you do? Most of it is just maths.

Comment: @Veedrac I have only done 1), i.e finding the function that I assume is my probabilty distribution. I don't know how to do 2,3,4!!

Comment: You don't know how to integrate?

Comment: yes, basically points 2,3 and 4!

Comment: I suggest a calculus course then... (?)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [SciPy](http://scipy.org/) stack. It includes great libraries for [probability and statistics](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html), [numerical integration](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) and [plotting](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html).